# How to convert Keras weights to JSON?

Tags: javascript, python, keras, tensorflow2.0

(This problem probably involves both python keras and js.)

TensorflowJS has the `model.loadWeights()` for a Keras LayersModel and the description is:

> Loads all layer weights from a JSON object.

> Porting Note: HDF5 weight files cannot be directly loaded in JavaScript / TypeScript. The utility script at scripts/pykeras.py offers means to convert them into JSON strings compatible with this method. Porting Note: TensorFlow.js Layers supports only loading by name currently.

> @param weights
> A JSON mapping weight names to weight values as nested arrays of numbers, or a NamedTensorMap, i.e., a JSON mapping weight names to tf.Tensor objects.

I have a hard time either understanding what this means or how to convert the weights to json. They link a `scripts/pykeras.py` file but not where could this be found (it is not in the node_modules.)

Any help?

Comment: Perhaps more information [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+HDF5+weight+site:stackoverflow.com)

Comment: Ok, I added JavaScript....

Comment: Can you use `JSON.stringify`? In what format do you have the weights?

Comment: So you have to read multiple binary files and create a JSON string? With Python or JavaScript?

Comment: I just found this link that could potentially help https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/386

Comment: Why would this involve JavaScript? Why can't you use `tf.io.loadWeights`?

Comment: @jabaa added an answer. Thanks for your good questions.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you may find only the weights for some models. These have the `modelTopology:null` when you convert them using `tensorflowjs_converter`.

Needless to say, this isn't necessary if your model topology is set to a meaningful value.

Yet if it is not too complicated of a NN, it may be worth to implement it in JS or TS and load the weights from external sources.

I did it for **VGG16**, but other models like the Mobile Nets are a lot more complex.

So this is how you can solve when *you have the model* but want to *load the weights*.

1. Get (load or write) the model (must be a layered model afaik.)
2. Then load the weights only

```js
const json = JSON.parse(readFileSync("path/to/model.json"))   
model.loadWeights(json.weightsManifest, false);
```